# Spark: sqlContext and dataFrame errors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code from the Spark example website, trying to run it from Eclipse, but it seems the code doesn't even compile.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object DataFrameExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount"); //.setMaster("local")
    conf.setMaster("local");

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext._
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
    people.registerTempTable("people")

    val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")

    // The results of SQL queries are DataFrames and support all the normal RDD operations.
    // The columns of a row in the result can be accessed by field index:
    teenagers.map(t => "Name: " + t(0)).collect().foreach(println)

    // or by field name:
    teenagers.map(t => "Name: " + t.getAs[String]("name")).collect().foreach(println)

    // row.getValuesMap[T] retrieves multiple columns at once into a Map[String, T]
    teenagers.map(_.getValuesMap[Any](List("name", "age"))).collect().foreach(println)
    // Map("name" -> "Justin", "age" -> 19)
  }
}
```

But then I got the following errors. Did I miss anything here? Thanks!

[image]

The same error (as text, from IntelliJ)

> Error:(18, 93) No TypeTag available for Person
>       val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
>                                                                                               ^

Comment: I have added the error message as text (as shown by IntelliJ). Could you please add the exact message as text from Eclipse as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the definition of class `Person`:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object DataFrameExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // [...]
  }
}
```

That definition must be outside of the method using it.

As for the reason: Have a look at [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-Scala-Error-value-toDF-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark/td-p/29878), a quote from there:

> 2- Move case class outside of the method:
>
> case class, by use of which you define the schema of the DataFrame, 
>   should be defined outside of the method needing it.

And it references https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649